# How to extends schema in graphql-compose

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am using the `graphql-compose` library. I am using the type composer to create classes and add it to schema composer and it builds the schema.

How to add (merge) another schema to schema composer? Or How to create an executable schema and add (merge) schema built by schema composer.

The schema what I need to add is from `apollo-upload-server`. Its docs declare schema like this:

```js
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: `scalar Upload`,
  resolvers: { Upload: GraphQLUpload }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is worked for me:

```js
import { mergeSchemas } from 'graphql-tools'
import { schemaComposer } from 'graphql-compose'
import {GraphQLUpload} from 'apollo-upload-server'

const composerSchema = schemaComposer.buildSchema()

const uploadSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: `scalar Upload`,
  resolvers: { Upload: GraphQLUpload }
})

const graphqlSchema = mergeSchemas({
    schemas: [composerSchema, uploadSchema]
})
```